# TYPO3: 404 not rewriting URL

Tags: http-status-code-404, typo3, realurl

So Im having quite trouble to get speaking URLs in TYPO3. I managed to make them work with this 2 lines in localconf.php

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS["FE"]["pageNotFound_handling"] = 'http://www.mysite.com/';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS["FE"]["pageNotFound_handling_statheader"] = 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found';
```

But the problem is that if I type a inexisting page, it even though it will direct me to the homepage, it wont rewrite the URL in the browser. Is there something that can be done about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the correct behavior of 404 not to change the URL in the browser. For redirects we have 30x http status codes. But you can't send two http status codes at the same time (404 and 301).

It is kind of bad practice to redirect to a homepage instead of showing a 404-not found message. The users may be irritated, asking themselves why they are now on the homepage and not at the URL they typed in...